# Large cardinals in ZF + DC + AD

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, axiom-of-choice, determinacy

The Axiom of Dependent Choice (DC) is often considered to be an "intuitive and non-controversial" version of choice used in the proofs of many theorems in Analysis. Similarly, the Axiom of Determinacy (AD) leads to especially nice properties for real numbers. Thus, in a sense, the system ZF + DC + AD is much "nicer" than ZFC, but maybe it restricts the "richness" of the set theoretic universe in some ways. Hence, I am wondering how this system interacts with large cardinals.

In particular:

1. Since AD is inconsistent with unrestricted Axiom of Choice (AC), are any of the "standard" large cardinal axioms - strongly inaccessible, Mahlo, measurable, rank-into-rank etc - inconsistent with ZF + DC + AD?
2. Conversely, can any such large cardinals - for example, strong inaccessibles - be *proved to exist* in this system? (Since the usual objection to proving their existence doesn't exist in this system)
3. Will the typical "size relations" between large cardinals in ZFC hold? For instance, is a measurable cardinal going to be inaccessible in this system? (The only proof I know uses well ordering) Is the smallest measurable greater than the smallest inaccessible?

I realize the question is quite broad - I am interested in sampling the kinds of results that may have been proved/conjectured.

Comment: Regarding 2, ZF + AD + DC proves $\omega_1$ is measurable (in the sense that it has a $\omega_1$-complete normal measure.) But I do not think it proves there is an inaccessible: If there is such, then cutting off the universe at the level of the inaccessible would be a model of ZF + AD + DC.

Comment: Also, it is known that if we have enough large cardinals (like a proper class of Woodin cardinals) then $L(\mathbb{R})$ is a model of ZF + AD + DC. I guess $L(\mathbb{R})$ also possesses moderate large cardinals like inaccessibles. (A cardinal $\kappa$ is inaccessible if $V_\kappa$ is a model of second-order $\mathsf{ZF}$. This definition is equivalent to a usual definition if we have Choice.)

Comment: It is consistent that every regular cardinal bellow $\Theta$ is measurable (specifically, $L(\mathbb R)$ will satisfy this). IIRC, there is a similar result about supercomapcts

Comment: Furthermore, in $ZF+AD$ every regular $\kappa<\aleph_{\omega_1}$ is Jonsson

Comment: The known results are much stronger. Kanamori's book on large cardinals is a good introduction. For Jónsson cardinals and the like, see for instance "Determinacy and Jónsson cardinals in $L(\mathbb R)$", MR3343535. Work by Sargsyan and others has pushed significantly what we know about large cardinals below $\Theta$ in models of $\mathsf{AD}$ under various assumptions.

Comment: $ZF+AD$ consistent with choiseless cardinals, example Berkeley cardinals?

Answer (score 9):

An unpublished theorem due to Woodin (which appears without proof as Theorem 7.35 of "In search of Ultimate L") states that if the $\Omega$ conjecture holds and there is a proper class of Woodin cardinals, then there is a partially ordered set $\mathbb P$ such that if $G\subseteq \mathbb P$ is a $V$-generic filter and $\mathbb R^* = (\mathbb R)^{V[G]}$, then $V(\mathbb R^*)$ is a model of AD. The hypotheses of this theorem are known to be consistent: in fact they hold in any model with a proper class of Woodins that satisfies Woodin's weakly homogeneous iteration hypothesis (WHIH), and this includes many of the current fine structure models by Steel's theorem that such models satisfy UBH; see Woodin's *The Axiom of Determinacy, Forcing Axioms, and the Nonstationary Ideal*, Definition 10.4 and Theorem 10.151. The model $V(\mathbb R^*)$ will in this context satisfy ZF + DC + AD plus  a proper class of Woodin cardinals. If there is a proper class of cardinals with some stronger large cardinal property in $V$, say a proper class of extendible cardinals for concreteness, then $V(\mathbb R^*)$ will have a proper class of extendible cardinals by standard lifting arguments; but the $\Omega$ conjecture is not known to be consistent with the existence of a proper class of extendible cardinals (or even a proper class of measurable Woodin cardinals).

In summary, if ZFC plus the $\Omega$ conjecture is consistent with a proper class of $X$ cardinals, then the Axiom of Determinacy is consistent with a proper class of $X$ cardinals, for any $X\in \{\text{Woodin, Extendible, Superduperhuge, etc}\}$. Moreover the $\Omega$ conjecture is consistent with a proper class of Woodin cardinals assuming the existence of a proper class of Woodin cardinals is consistent.

Comment: Superduperhuge. ☺️